# Reprocess RowPrePaint after datatable update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that highlight "problem" cells to the user. The user can then right click and select update which will change the data in the datasource (datatable) and reprocess the row.  This all works great.

To highlight the cells I have RowPrePaint processing the cells as they are displayed.  This doesn't seem to trigger an event after the datatable is updated.

In thinking about the process I believe this is the correct operation as the datagrid is already displayed and the RowPrePaint doesn't get hit again in the debugger until I exit the form and re-enter.

I tried using mydgView.Refresh(); but that didn't seem to do anything....  Can I force the RowPrePaint to rebuild the view on the selected row?

```
        private void dgvUsers_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bIDWarning = Convert.ToBoolean(dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IDWarning"].Value.ToString());
        Color IDColor = Color.FromArgb( Convert.ToInt32( dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["nIDColor"].Value));


        if ( bIDWarning )
        {
            dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Style.BackColor = IDColor;// Color.Yellow;

            dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].ToolTipText = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ToolTip"].Value.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You don't need to use `RowPrePaint` to do such a thing, anyway it's still unclear on what you want, you should post some snippet of code to show how you use the `RowPrePaint` and a little on why you want to use such an event, I think there may be some **straightforward** way to do instead.

Comment: Its just the way I found to color individual cells... Is there another way that I'm not aware of?